# Getting a null score vector using princomp funtion in R

Tags: r, statistics, pca

I'm trying to do PCA analysis on some data. I'm not given the raw data, just the correlation matrix in this way:

```
      Tmax  Tmin     P     H    PT     V  Vmax
Tmax  1.00  0.70 -0.08 -0.41 -0.09 -0.23 -0.08
Tmin  0.70  1.00 -0.30  0.07  0.14 -0.03 -0.01
P    -0.08 -0.30  1.00 -0.18 -0.13 -0.29 -0.25
H    -0.41  0.07 -0.18  1.00  0.32 -0.15 -0.19
PT   -0.09  0.14 -0.13  0.32  1.00  0.11  0.07
V    -0.23 -0.03 -0.29 -0.15  0.11  1.00  0.83
Vmax -0.08 -0.01 -0.25 -0.19  0.07  0.83  1.00
```

For this I'm trying to use the princomp() function since it has the covmat option so I can introduce data as a correlation matrix. For the pca analysis I'm using the following code:

```
pca_prim <- princomp(covmat=Primavera, cor = T, scores = TRUE)
```

I need the scores in order to plot a biplot in following steps but the scores vector I get is null:

```
biplot(pca_prim)
```

```
Error in biplot.princomp(pca_prim) : object 'pca_prim' has no scores
```

```
pca_prim$scores
```

```
NULL
```

I can't seem to find what the problem is in order to get the scores. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `prcomp`, this works: `pca2 <- prcomp(Primavera); biplot(pca2)`.

Comment: The thing is that since I'm using a correlation matrix as data prcomp() is not ready for that type of input, from what I can tell from the documentation. Only princomp() gives accurate results

Comment: Have you tried the code I've posted?

Comment: Yes, it gives the scores but the results are not the same as using princomp so I don't know if this scores are correct

Comment: Why shouldn't they be? `prcomp` has been around for long enough for users to trust its results, errors like those would have been detected and corrected a long time ago.

Comment: You cannot get scores from only the correlation matrix, only the loadings. The scores are computed from the original data and the loadings matrix.